# Why isn't my custom form element theme function being called?

Tags: forms

In my module I have a function that returns a form:

```
function mymodule_myform($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['fs_refine'] = array('#type' => 'fieldset');
    $form['fs_refine']['refine'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#theme' => 'toggles',
        '#title' => t('Refine results by category:'),
        '#options' => array(
            1 => t('Cat 1'), 
            2 => t('Cat 2'),
            3 => t('Cat 3')),
        '#default_value' => array(1, 2, 3)
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit')
    );
    return $form;
}
```

I render the form with:

```
drupal_render(drupal_get_form('mymodule_myform'));
```

I have the following functions in my module:

```
function theme_toggles($vars) {
    die;
}

function mymodule_theme_toggles($vars) {
    die;
}

function mymodule_toggles($vars) {
    die;
}
```

I want to call a theme function for my checkboxes form element so that I can customise the HTML output of each checkbox. My theme functions are obviously not being called, because my page would by dying if one of them was.

How do I fix this and theme my form elements using #theme?

Comment: function theme_toggles($vars) {
    die;
}
should work.
 * Clear cache
 * Instead die, put print 'something';exit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you need several things combined in order for this to work:

1. `#theme => unique_name_for_theme_function` on the form element.
2. In your template.php mytemplate_theme() function you need to return an array something like: `array( 'unique_name_for_theme_function' => array('function') => 'myfunc') );`. This was the bit I was missing.
3. Then in your template.php you need to add a myfunc. I found it easiest to just google "Drupal theme_form_element", "Drupal theme_checkboxes" or whatever, and then copy paste the code I found in to a mytemplate_theme_checkboxes function which I then modified to suit my needs.
4. Then you need to flush cache for Drupal to find your theme function.